# aws_shield_protection Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cdk

I am struggling to find a way to include all load balancers with certain tag value's (e.g. Shield protection = ON) in an aws account.
Currently i have a map of arn's in a variable and running a for loop. This method work's but not in an efficient way; since every time I have to add the ARN of a new Load balancer manually.

```
resource "aws_shield_protection" "this" {
  for_each = var.listofarn

  name         = "shield protection".each.key
  resource_arn = each.key
}

variable listofarn {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
  appx_alb="arn::xxxxx"
  appy_alb="arn:yyyyy"
 }
}
```

Is there a way to use data resource "aws_lb".
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data source **wouldn't help much**. `aws_lb` data source can only return **one alb**. You can't use it to get information about all your ALBs. You would have to run the `aws_lb` data source in a for_loop with tags or some ALB id.

But you could overcome your issue through development of an [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). Since its a fully custom data source, it can return information about all your ALBs in the form you want.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the reply; are there any examples that resembles this problem & you can share for the external data source. Terraform documentation does help much.